# Как можно строку с пробелом преобразовать в число?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно такую строку: `12 34`, `123 456`преобразовать в число?

```js
var counter = 2;
    num = $('i').text();


console.log(num);
console.log(parseInt(num));
console.log(num*counter);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
  
<span><i>120 250</i> коп.</span>
```

Comment: убрать перед преобразованием пробел

Comment: `num = num.replace(/\s+/g, "");`

Comment: @kff, и вот так `parseInt(num.replace(/\s+/g, ''),10)`. спасибо решила

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решила так `parseInt(num.replace(/\s+/g, ''),10)`:

```js
var num = $('i').text();


console.log(num);
console.log(parseInt(num.replace(/\s+/g, ''),10));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
  
<span><i>120 250</i> коп.</span>
```

спасибо всем!

Comment: что за counter?

Comment: @Grundy, да то со своего примера скопировала, еще на него умножать надо будет num

Comment: Ну ты хоть напиши как именно решила, а не просто кусок кода

Answer (score 5):

```
parseInt(String(num).replace(/ /g, ''))
```

**UPD**

`String(num)` нужен, чтобы избежать ошибки

> replace is not a function

в случае, если **num** оказалось просто числом. Например, если этот код используется в функции, и один раз на её вход подати не '12', а 12.

Comment: в чем смысл _String(num)_?

Comment: @Grundy, извиняюсь, что отдельным ответом. Не даёт сделать коммент. `String(num)`, чтобы избежать ошибки `replace is not a function` в случае, если num оказалось просто числом. Например, если этот код используется в функции, и один раз на её вход подати не '12', а 12.

Comment: @Саша зарегистрируйтесь - а то вам не дас нормально комментировать собственные посты